# Reactor: Thread-safe way to propagate thread local variables either using decorated scheduler or subscriberContext?

Tags: java, kotlin, project-reactor

I am currently using Reactor in my project. For multi-threading with Reactor, is there a best practice for how to propagate thread local variables? We currently have one approach where we use SubscriberContext and Schedulers. The other approach we tried is using decorated Schedulers via Schedulers.setFactory(ThreadLocalSchedulerFactory) and setting a Context object in each thread. Is there anything wrong with either approach and why?

We are slightly favoring the second approach because it may be more straightforward to our developers but we are not sure if it is robust enough.